ubuntu 24.04.1 apt update does not work when connected only to local repository manager
I have installed a clean Ubuntu 24.04.1 and blocked internet access to it. All the other services like ntp and dns are supplied through my Domain Controller. In order to download packages, I have configured Ubuntu to connect to a local repository manager (proget) that is configured to go to the internet and download the packages to a central location. When I try to run sudo apt update I always get a gpg error related to "InRelease" and no matter what I do, I can't update.
I have followed manuals that convert asc files of the repository to gpg and imported them and I get an error of public keys. I have imported my certificate authority ca cert and it didn't help. I have tried using an insecure repository, but I got the same outcome.
Do you have any ideas? Can my setup work at all? Do I have to connect the Ubuntu one time to the internet to download general packages and then close it again?
I had an Ubuntu with the same version that I was able to download files this way, but I wasn't the one who installed it and I do not know if it was connected to the internet before.

Can you post the exact InRelease error?

yes, will take me a couple of days.
